# Close a popup from an internal button - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox in a WPF application which contains a list and 'OK' button. I would like the ComboBox popup area to be closed when a user click on the OK button which in the ComboBox.
(I want the click event to change the property: IsDropDownOpen of the ComboBox
How can I cause an internal content to close its container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try replacing the `Button` with a `ToggleButton` and bind the `ToggleButton.IsChecked` property to the `ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen` property using and 'inverse `bool` `Converter`' (a `Converter` class that returns the opposite of the `bool` input value.)

The *only* problem with this is that you would need to 'un-toggle' the `ToggleButton` each time the `ComboBox` drop down opened.

Comment: If you make this binding TwoWay, the `ToggleButton` should be automatically be untoggled when the DropDown opens, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Logical/Visual Tree to get the containing `ComboBox`:

```
        DependencyObject prop = sender as DependencyObject;
        while (prop != null && !(prop is ComboBox))
        {
            prop = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(prop);
        }
        if (prop != null)
        {
            ((ComboBox) prop).IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }
```

Of course thats just a quick and dirty solution and should be cleaned up. ;)